# curl_exec() does not return simple string

Tags: php, curl

My code is the following.

```
<?php

$name= "Gustavo";
$pass= "Palomino";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://web.njit.edu/~gep5/welcome.php");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            http_build_query(array('name' => $name, 'pass' => $pass)));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$answer = curl_exec($ch);
echo $answer;
curl_close($ch);


if ($answer=="ok")

   echo "logged in";
else
  echo "login failed";
?>
```

When I execute this code I get $answer to be ---- echo "ok"; -----

welcome.php is the following

```
<?php
echo "ok";
?>
```

I thought that this should simply return a string --- ok --- to $answer from the first code.

Apparently it returns the entire code of welcome.php

Any help with this would be very appreciated.

Comment: and what does that html file say ? "Moved Permanently" ... your are submitting to the wrong url

Comment: The curl is sending to the http, not https, your htaccess must have a rewrite rule in place.

Comment: well I have changed the url to https://.... the returning string is 'echo "ok"' no apostrophe. Why doesn't it return just ok?

Comment: It isn't executing as PHP. Do other php pages execute as you'd expect on this server?

Comment: i'm not sure. i'm actually just running it from my terminal i executed index.php simply as "php index.php"

Comment: Are you sure your welcome.php is that and not `<?php>`?

Comment: So Chris. 
you were right. My welcome.php file was

<?php>
echo "ok";
?>

Why did this make a big difference?

Comment: The opening PHP needs to be `<?php` the `>` made it interpreted as an HTML file. In the browser you weren't seeing the `<?php>` because it interpreted that as an element. I can't find any actually documentation on the PHP opening tag and whitespace requirement but I'm pretty sure there is one..

Comment: Thank you very much....

In welcome.php I will be able to access the value as $_POST['name']; am i correct.

Comment: Should be, if not try `print_r($_POST);` to see what is being submitted.

Comment: Thank you Chris, it works as it should now. i appreciate the help...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a setting...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that curl option does but Chris figured out what my dumb self did wrong. Thank you.